# Matplotlib2tikz Increase spacing between ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib2tikz

I am using `matplotlib2tikz` to plot a barchart. However, the ticks are not spaced out enough. How do I increase the spacing between the results?

My code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

h = [47]*90
labels = ['a']*90
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(len(labels) * 0.45, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects1 = ax.bar(sp.arange(len(h)), h, 0.35, color='r')
ax.set_xticks(sp.arange(len(labels)))
ax.set_xlabel("X Label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Label")
ax.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=14, rotation="vertical")
ax.set_title("Test plot")
from matplotlib2tikz import save as tikz_save
tikz_save("test.tex")
```

And the result:
[image]

I want the labels to be more spaced out so that they are readable - how do I achieve that? (Without manually editing the resulting tikz code)

Answer (score 1):

If you must show all the labels, then your options are a bit limited. You can reduce the whitespace between the bars and the side of the axis, you can reduce the fontsize of the ticklabels, and you can make the axis wider. Not really much else you can do, I think.

- To reduce the whitespace, add e.g. `ax.set_xlim([-0.5,89.5])` (or make it depend on `len(h)`).
- To reduce the fontsize of the ticklabels, add `extra_axis_parameters={'xticklabel style={font=\\scriptsize}'}` to the call of `tikz_save`. (Alternatively `\\footnotesize` or `\\tiny`.)
- To increase the width, add `figurewidth='15cm'` to the call of `tikz_save`. (Adjust width as appropriate.)

Hence, with

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

h = [47]*90
labels = ['a']*90
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(len(labels) * 0.45, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
rects1 = ax.bar(sp.arange(len(h)), h, 0.35, color='r')
ax.set_xticks(sp.arange(len(labels)))
ax.set_xlim([-0.5,89.5])
ax.set_xlabel("X Label")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Label")
ax.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=14, rotation="vertical")
ax.set_title("Test plot")
from matplotlib2tikz import save as tikz_save
tikz_save("test.tex",figurewidth='15cm',figureheight='6cm',extra_axis_parameters={'xticklabel style={font=\\scriptsize}'})
```

You get

[image: LaTeX output]